# Sql server BCP execute inside vb6

Tags: sql-server, vb6, bcp

I want to execute a BCP command in a VB6 application, how can i do it?

I tried this code:

```
BCPCMD = " 'BCP ""SELECT * FROM TABLE"" QUERYOUT C:\FILE.TXT -c -t -T -S MYSERVER' "

sql = "EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL " & BCPCMD

db.Execute (sql)
```

The code execute with no errors, but dont generate any file :/

Comment: Why are you generating a BCP string to run from xpcmdshell inside sql?

Comment: Do you have `sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1` set?

Comment: I found the error: I was trying to generate the file from a temporary table. I just create a normal table and referenced the database name in the table: > BCPCMD = " 'BCP ""SELECT * FROM DB..TABLE"" QUERYOUT C:\FILE.TXT -c -t > -T -S MYSERVER' " Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

There's a general misconception out there about BCP. BCP is an executable. BCP is not a SQL command. You see a lot of information on the internet with details on how to execute BCP from a SQL statement or stored procedure. The usual answer involves using the stored proc XP_CMDSHELL to run the BCP executable. For this solution to work some adjustments need to be made to the SQL Server configuration.

Since you are running BCP from within a VB application you can run the BCP executable without having a pre-existing connection to the database server from your application. The command line statement to run looks something like:

```
 bcp.exe "SELECT * FROM TABLE" QUERYOUT C:\FILE.TXT -c -t -T -SmyServer -UtheUsername -PthePassword
```

Answer (score 1):

Decades ago (sweet lord), I wrote a VB6 (or maybe VB5 at the time) wrapper for handling BCP from Visual Basic.  I used it for years.

[Enjoy](http://www.vbrad.com/pf.asp?p=source/src_bcp.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I'm eager to know whether BCP can be used in Management studio ?? As far as i know it's  a command prompt utility ...

Comment: Yes, it can be used in Management Studio, i have some SPs running BCP commands, but now i want to run the BCP in a VB6 app. And like a i said, the code runs without erros, but dont generate the file.

Comment: I found the error:

I was trying to generate the file from a temporary table. I just create a normal table and referenced the database name in the table:

> BCPCMD = " 'BCP ""SELECT * FROM **DB..TABLE**"" QUERYOUT C:\FILE.TXT -c -t
> -T -S MYSERVER' "

Thanks all!